# How does Alonso know where Roger keeps his money?

Tags: training-day

In *Training Day*, Alonso needs money fast and decides to steal several million dollars from a dealer named Roger. Somehow he knows that the money is stashed under the kitchen floor.

**How would Alonso know where the money is?**

Roger may have told him, but why would he do that? Is there a good reason for Roger to tell *anyone* where his money is?

Comment: to clarify - he doesn't know the exact location. he seems to stomp his foot on the kitchen floor until he finds a hollow space. but it seemed odd that he knew it was under the kitchen floor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experience.

- Alonso has been a detective for many years, he has a gut feeling where criminals hide their cash, drugs and guns.
- There is a scene Alonso sticks a pen into Snoopy Dog's mouth, how does he know it?
- Alonso asks one of two rapists if he has got anything on them, that rapist says No. Alonso starts searching his socks and finds money and drugs.
- Alonso knows where to look for a stash of cash from that old drug lord in his kitchen, he does not the exact location but it is hard to hide a huge box of cash.
- Alonso is not sure exactly where sandman hides his money, he goes into the bedroom and starts searching bit by bit, you can only hide a stash of cash in certain spaces.